# Springboot datasource exception

Tags: spring-boot

when i put jpaDependencency compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
i am getting this Exception

> 2018-02-28 13:18:20.062  WARN 15208 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type
>   NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on
>   the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Database driver JAR. If you include an embedded one, Spring Boot will pick and configure it by default.

You can add:

```
compile("com.h2database:h2")
```

Check out this getting started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: i have applications property also but could'nt configure hibernate data source 2018-03-01 01:32:58.513  INFO 15992 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-03-01 01:32:58.521  INFO 15992 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-03-01 01:32:58.521  INFO 15992 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist